# Mapping based on condition in TRUE/FALSE big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table:

```
name    type                        order
Hokben  6_image-Resto Siap Santap   3
Hokben  Hokben                      2
Hokben  home_icon-Terdekat          4
Hokben  home_icon-Terlaris          2
Jelly   Jelly                       2
Jelly   home_icon-Terlaris          1
Aqua    Resto                       3
Aqua    home_icon-Terdekat          5
```

I Want to know that home_icon-Terdekat are the highest order or not based on name. The result like this:

```
name    type                        order result
Hokben  6_image-Resto Siap Santap   3     FALSE
Hokben  Hokben                      2     FALSE
Hokben  home_icon-Terdekat          4     TRUE
Hokben  home_icon-Terlaris          2     FALSE
Jelly   Jelly                       2     FALSE
Jelly   home_icon-Terdekat          1     FALSE
Aqua    Resto                       3     FALSE
Aqua    home_icon-Terdekat          4     TRUE
```

Comment: Just wanted to be sure about the question, you wanted to setup a condition where home_icon-Terdekat has the highest order in the type column?

Comment: To clarify. Jelly 2 must be TRUE or FALSE?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t1.name,
        t1.type,
        t1.order,
        case when t1.type = 'home_icon-Terdekat' and t1.order = (max(t1.order) over(partition by t1.name)) then TRUE else FALSE end as result,
from    YOUR_TABLE t1
```

Comment: how about like new data up there?

Comment: @Azuri, I some changed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
select *, `order` = max(`order`) over() as result
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: how about devided by name? in your script the max is for overall data. in my example data Jelly the condition order in type home_icon-Terdekat (1) is less than type Jelly (2). So the result will false

Comment: use `over(partition by name)` instead of `over()`

Comment: I have tried that but the result same like over()

Comment: Not sure then what it is that you want to achieve!